# R Shiny - checkbox toggle ggplot graph tableGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make a Shiny app that I can toggle a table on the graph. Sometimes the values on the graph will be covered by the table, so this is the solution I thought of.

I cannot figure out how to format the if statement in the ggplot setup to make the table toggle. I included the entire example code below with two different attempts where the toggle does not accomplish anything. What is the correct way to code the toggle?

Alternatively, if there is a better way to avoid the table overlapping the data issue please let me know.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     checkboxInput("checkbox",label = "Graph legend on/off (not working yet)", value = TRUE)
    ),
   mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("value"),
    plotOutput("p")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$value <- renderText({input$checkbox})
  
  xvalues <- 1:5
  yvalues <- round(runif(5),2)
  graphableDF <- data.frame(xvalues, yvalues)
  
  mytable <- cbind(X = xvalues,Y = yvalues)
  
  # You can comment this and uncomment the next if statement to see what the goal is
  # output$p <- renderPlot({
  # p <- ggplot(graphableDF, aes(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)) +
  #   geom_line(color="black") +
  #   ylim(0,1) +
  #   annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin = 4.5, ymin = .65)
  # p
  # })
  
  #Currently, this entire section does nothing even if the button is toggled
  # if (renderText({input$checkbox}) = TRUE) {
  # output$p <- renderPlot({
  #   p <- ggplot(graphableDF, aes(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)) +
  #     geom_line(color="grey") +
  #     ylim(0,1) +
  #     annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin = 4.5, ymin = .65)
  #   p
  # })}else{
  # output$p <- renderPlot({
  #   p <- ggplot(graphableDF, aes(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)) +
  #     geom_line(color="grey") +
  #     ylim(0,1)
  #   p
  # })}
  
  #Also does not work
  # output$p <- renderPlot({
  #   p <- ggplot(graphableDF, aes(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)) +
  #     geom_line(color="black") +
  #     ylim(0,1) +
  #     if (renderText({input$checkbox}) = TRUE) {
  #       annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin = 4.5, ymin = .65)
  #     }
  #   p
  # })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("checkbox",label = "Graph legend on/off", value = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("value"),
      plotOutput("p")
    )))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$value <- renderText({input$checkbox})
  
  xvalues <- 1:5
  yvalues <- round(runif(5),2)
  graphableDF <- data.frame(xvalues, yvalues)
  
  mytable <- cbind(X = xvalues,Y = yvalues)
  
  # works fine
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(graphableDF, aes(x=xvalues, y=yvalues)) +
      geom_line(color="black") +
      {if (input$checkbox) annotation_custom(tableGrob(mytable), xmin = 4.5, ymin = .65) } +
      ylim(0,1) + xlim(1,5.7)
    p
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]